# vbsscript run cmd command with parametrs

Tags: vbscript, cmd, lpr

I have a folder in witch .pcl and .ps files are written.

I want those files to be printed, the only possibillity to do this if found is cmd **LPR** command

the script is:

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
currentPath = "c:\printAll\" 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

    if files.name <> "printAll" then
        'msgbox("printing "&files.name) 
                                oShell.run "cmd.exe /C LPR -S SRV00APP.N-IX.LOCAL -P HP400MFP    #{shFolder}/#{files.name} "


    end if
next
```

How can i pass attributes as **currentPath** or **files.name** to cmd line command?

Comment: [String concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w(v=vs.84).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building the string like:

```
 oShell.run "cmd.exe /C LPR -S SRV00APP.N-IX.LOCAL -P HP400MFP    #{" & shFolder & "}/#{" & files.name "} "
```

(not sure if you need all the brackets etc)

Comment: thanks! ended with: `oShell.run "cmd.exe /C LPR -S "& printerHost &" -P "& printerName &"    " & currentPath & "\" & files.name & " "`